# Will tidal heating on Jovian moons ever cease?

Tags: orbital-resonance, galilean-moons

Will tidal heating on Jupiter's Galilean moons, specifically Io & Europa ever cease?

I thought not, since they are occasionally in orbital resonance with each other and Ganymede, thus preventing the orbit from becoming circular. Does this effectively mean that tidal heating will continue well into the Solar System's foreseeable future?